# Retrieve a file on a pc that's only saved on a USB but not on the pc itself

Tags: usb

as the title says, I really want to know if it's possible to open a document that's created on a pc but then saved on a USB. It was a computer of the company I worked for, so I'm not sure if they have any 'access' to things that we were doing on that computer?
ALSO I'm not sure if I saved the file first on my USB or first on the computer and then cut and paste it on my USB. Could that make any difference?

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: In short, yes. For specifics, what OS were you using and what application(s)? Are you trying to recover a lost file - or trying to confirm that the company doesn't have access to it?

Comment: I want to know of the company used my file after I left there... It was an Apple computer

Comment: What software? And how long ago?

Comment: I made it in Word on a Macbook. And it was in January, but I don't know when they checked the computer. Could be the day before I left of the exact day i made the document. I don't know. It's just that I made a script for a show and now they posted a show with the exact same name as I wrote... Don't know if it's coïncidence or if they really 'stole' it.  Little bit freaking out :s

Comment: Unfortunately, it's possible. And even if you could prove they copied your file, they could have a claim to rights over work done on company property on company time.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a document on a PC, then even if you didn't actively save it on the PC's hard drive, it's possible (but not certain) that copies are still accessible on the PC

- Autosave copies could have been created and not automatically deleted
- The application you used could have created temporary files before saving to the USB

Additionally, if you saved it on the PC and then deleted it, it could still be accessible from the PC's trash / recycle bin, or (requiring some determination) by undeleting files.